# Combining C# Windows Form Applications, Master Solution

Tags: c#, winforms

Rather than have a large collection of small desktop applications, I was wondering if there's a way I can combine them into one 'Master Form' with links to each?

I have many similar applications and the ideal situation would be to have almost like a website hierarchy, where the user can navigate to the application they want.

I have considered a solution that sits on top of the rest and calls the others in some way, but I can't find if this is possible or not, is every separate application effectively stand-alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can directly disign on master form for it.

keep menus for each exe(Application) and,

give command in following way for onclick of that menu in master>>

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("billing.exe",strCmdText);
```

Or directly `Process.Start("C:\\");`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, where do I places the .exe files in the directory for this to work?

Comment: where did you put them?